# How to get a list of 1's and 0's based on any function through a map with Python... I am getting the error object is not callable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, any

In short what I am trying to do is based on a list `objects = ["bison", "elephant", "horse", "ibis", "sky", "mountain", "building", "flower", "sand", "tree", "field", "road", "tower", "ocean", "cliff", "waterfall"]` get the number 1 if that list of strings contains is substring of the elements from another list otherwise 0
For instance, I have another list name as `Lista =['dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain']` since it contains sky and mountain
It should return `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

What I have till now is the following code

```
Lista = ['dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain']
objects = ["bison", "elephant", "horse", "ibis", "sky", "mountain", "building", "flower", "sand", "tree", "field", "road", "tower", "ocean", "cliff", "waterfall"]
returnList = []
for obj in objects:
  for element in lista: returnList.append(1) if any(map(obj in element, obj)) else returnList.append(0)
```

Which is giving me the folowing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    printBoolArray(readObjects)
  File "main.py", line 10, in printBoolArray
    for m in lista: returnList.append(1) if any(map(n in m, m)) else returnList.append(0)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Hopefully there is something that can be done and if possible I would like it to be done using the **any** function

Comment: `map()` expects a callable in the first argument. You are passing `n in m` which is not callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines will work for you:

```py
Lista = ['dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain']
objects = ["bison", "elephant", "horse", "ibis", "sky", "mountain", "building", "flower", "sand", "tree", "field", "road", "tower", "ocean", "cliff", "waterfall"]
returnList = []
for obj in objects:
    if any(obj in elem for elem in Lista):
        returnList.append(1)
    else:
        returnList.append(0)

print(returnList)
```

```
Out: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note, this is not the most efficient way of doing this, but the solution might get complicated if we try to optimize it.  Feel free to drop a comment if you have questions.

And here is a one liner if you like list comprehension:

```py
returnList = [int(any(obj in elem for elem in Lista)) for obj in objects]
```